# Failed to connect to video room in Twilio

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

I'm woking on building a web calling application in React + Twilio API. But it failed to post API and this is unable to connect to video room because of the token error.

an error:

```
POST https://ecs.us1.twilio.com/v2/Configuration 403

Unable to connect to Room: The authorization with Token failed
```

I have set up Twilio account like below:

1) Get Twilio credentials and API key
[image: credentials]

[image]

2) This time I use **TEST Credentials**. And I set up `ACCOUNT_SID`, `API_KEY_SID`, and `API_KEY_SECRET` to `.env`.

```js
REACT_APP_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_TWILIO_API_KEY_SID = 'SKXXXXXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

3) Set up twilio configuration with API document

```
import twilio from "twilio";

const AccessToken = twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

// Substitute your Twilio AccountSid and ApiKey details
const ACCOUNT_SID = process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const API_KEY_SID = process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_API_KEY_SID;
const API_KEY_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET;

// Create an Access Token
const accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET);

// Set the Identity of this token
accessToken.identity = "my-user";

// Grant access to Video
const grant = new VideoGrant();
grant.room = "cool room";
accessToken.addGrant(grant);

// Serialize the token as a JWT
const twilioToken = accessToken.toJwt();

export default twilioToken;
```

4) call a room

```js
    connect(twilioToken, { name: "my-new-room" }).then(
      room => {
        console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
        room.on("participantConnected", participant => {
          console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participant}`);
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
      }
    );
```

But it failed. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

Passed with **Live Account**. I don't know why but Test account is not working.